# SSIS Lookup failure even though all columns are matching

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am getting strangest of the errors. Bunch of lookups are failing even though the data from source is exactly same as data from destination.

There are 4 columns from source and all are of varchar type. I am using these source data to match from destination using a cache connection manager.

I run the queries side by side and do the comparison and they are the same.
I also put them in notepad++ using the 'Show All symbols' to look for any special characters but i don't see any.

Any idea what may be causing the issue?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Look for possible nonprinting characters... I had this issue: I was solving it for some time and finaly I used HEX viewer to found that in one datasource one column had LF at the end of the string...

Or maybe just code pages of matching columns don't match?